# Can this question be restored? Or should I repost?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question [Can I sue my sibling for not sharing rent money from inherited property?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79295/can-i-sue-my-sibling-for-not-sharing-rent-money-from-inherited-property) was closed by Dale M as calling for legal advice, and then locked by "community bot".

I flagged it for moderator intervention, requesting that it be unlocked so that I could edit it into a question that clearly did not ask for legal advice. The flag was marked "helpful", but the question is still locked, and shows as having been returned to the stack from which it was migrated.

Does this mean that there is now no chance of this question being unlocked and potentially reopened?  If so, I plan to post a new question using the facts of this one, and link it to the original.

(Note that it was **not** originally my question, I was a prospective answerer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, it can't - repost if you like

The reason it can't is that it was a migrated question (from Personal Finance & Money). Once one of those is closed, the question bounces back to the original site and we can't do anything with it.

Comment: You can use the "Unlock" option in the "Mod" menu.  I've just tested this on a rejected migration and it allows the question to be edited and reopened by non-moderators.

Comment: @Ryan I don't see any such menu. Where on the screen is it please? or could it be only available if one is a mod?

Comment: @DavidSiegel it's only available for moderators (sorry for the slow response).  For reference, [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8KTW.gif) (this is a spam answer, not a rejected migrated question, but the general idea is the same).